# issues with fetching data from models

Tags: database, django, django-models

One of my model is abstract model, which is inherited by another model.

```
class SelectedProduct(models.Model):

    sku = fields.SKUField()
    description = CharField(_("Description"), max_length=200)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(_("Quantity"), default=0)
    unit_price = fields.MoneyField(_("Unit price"), default=Decimal("0"))
    total_price = fields.MoneyField(_("Total price"), default=Decimal("0"))

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

inherited  model

```
class OrderItem(SelectedProduct):

    order = models.ForeignKey("Order", related_name="items")
```

Now if I run this command in my views   `orderItem=OrderItem.objects.all()` and in my templated `{{passed_variable}}` it returns

`[<OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, <OrderItem: >, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']`

means no id, description etc. and if I specify `{{passed_variable.id}}` in my template then it shows nothing.

Comment: Can you show the actuak table names as  well as the sql command that work?

Comment: SELECT sku FROM shop_orderitem WHERE order_id = %s", [58]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`orderItem=OrderItem.objects.all()` returns a list(queryset) of items

You need to loop over the items

in python:

```
for one_order_item in orderItem:
    print one_order_item.id
```

in django templates:

```
{% for one_order_item in passed_variable %}
       {{ one_order_iten.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I know that.... But if we only write that variable without for loop it shows an array of all data.  And I have mention that array which i got. just the name of table but no value <OrderItem:no value here >,...] . and if i use for loop than it shows nothing........and if in place of table orderitem i mention another table... it shows the data...means there is something wrong with the table.....

Comment: @Inforian which database are you using?

Comment: @Inforian can you access the database and see the records?

Comment: oh yes .... the problem with only this table......so now I am using raw sql queries for this

Comment: @Inforian try remove the table and create it again, raw sql when using django is not the right way :)